# Visual Studio Snippets with subString variable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I'm trying to setup an environment to work with SenchaTouch in VS2010 and I'm writing some Snippets using Snippet Designer.
I wonder if somebody could explain me how to make variable one part of a string:
For example:

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.controller.Notes",
```

I want the user able to edit the Notes name and the NotesApp name but without changing ".controller")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it was easier than I thought (snippets basic) and I was too lazy the first time:

```
Ext.define("$appli$.controller.$control$", {

    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    config: {
        refs: {            
           // firstView: "firstView",
           // secondView: "secondView"
        },

    // Remainder of the controller’s code 

});
```